# Problema al crear Foreign Keys en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Estoy haciendo una base de datos con 4 tablas, las cuales van unidas por foreign key pero me tira un error al crear la tabla Producto.

```
create table Sucursal(
rucSucursal int (10) not null,
Nombre_Sucursal varchar (45) not null,
Direccion_Sucursal varchar (45) not null,
primary key (rucSucursal)
)engine = InnoDB;

create table Proveedor_Producto (
rucProveedor int (10) not null,
Nombre_Proveedor varchar (45)
) engine = InnoDB;

create table Tipo_Producto (
idTipo_Producto int not null,
Nombre_TipoProducto varchar(45)
) engine = InnoDB;

create table Producto(
idProducto int not null,
Nombre_Producto varchar(45) not null,
Precio_Producto decimal not null,
Marca_Producto varchar(45) not null,
Stock_Producto int not null,
rucSucursal_fk int (10) not null,
rucProveedor_fk int (10) not null,
idTipo_Producto_fk int not null,
 primary key (idProducto),
index (rucSucursal_fk),
index (rucProveedor_fk),
index (idTipo_Producto_fk),
constraint rucSucursal_fk foreign key (rucSucursal_fk) references Sucursal(rucSucursal),
constraint rucProveedor_fk foreign key (rucProveedor_fk) references Proveedor_Producto(rucProveedor),
constraint idTipo_Producto_fk foreign key (idTipo_Producto_fk) references Tipo_Producto (idTipo_Producto)
) engine = InnoDB;
```

El error es:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `farmacity`.`producto` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")    0.203 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fijate que no tenés un índice en las claves referenciadas de las últimas 2 FK.
Es decir, probá con que **Proveedor_Producto.rucProveedor** y **Tipo_Producto.idTipo_Producto** tengan sus respectivos índices en sus tablas, y luego agregá la FK en **Producto**.

Comment: Gracias, no me había dado cuenta.